# How to use "private use area" fonts in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts

I'm trying to use font icons in my IOS application, I can able to display images from miscellaneous

[image]

When i use the below code image is displaying

`[Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello" size:50]];
  [Label setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\u2692"]];`

[image]

But When i am trying to use code from private user area nothing is displaying

```
     [Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello" size:50]];
    [Label setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\uE756"]];
```

[image]

Can anybody please help me, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check, what `+fontWithName:size:` returns to be sure, that the font is found.

Comment: yes this is worked for me @AminNegm-Awad, i missed to add file in copy bundle resources

Comment: Cool. I made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the custom font file to the resources by adding it in the copy files build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom font reference in copy bundle resources
[image]